# Can't save empty string into field value

Tags: magento

I need to change value of NULL-field to empty string (in sales_flat_order table).
I tried this code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('to' => $endDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $comment  = $order->getCustomerNote();
    if (is_null($comment)) {
        $order->setData('customer_note', '');
        try {
            $order->save();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();  exit;
        }
    }
}
```

But in base I see still NULL value in this filed.
If I change empty string to any non-empty it works fine.
How can I update NULL value field to empty string?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you've checked that there is a column called customer_note in the sales_flat_order table? It's not a default column, that's why I ask. If you always need it to be an empty string why not just change the column definition on the table to be empty string as default instead of NULL `ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order ALTER COLUMN customer_note SET DEFAULT ' ' ;` and then manually update your existing records on the db with `UPDATE sales_flat_order SET customer_note = '' WHERE customer_note = NULL AND state = 'complete';`. Does the value actually get saved in DB when you call save?

Comment: Yes, "customer_note" is own column. And it needs default NULL value. In frontend I make case: if customer_note is null then place textarea, else if it's not empty string then show it. Finally, I decided my problem with derict sql (in cron job): Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->query(..). I just surprised that Magento does not allow update null value to empty string :(

Answer (score 0):

The empty string is set to *null* in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::prepareColumnValue()`:

```
case 'varchar':
case 'mediumtext':
case 'text':
case 'longtext':
    $value  = (string)$value;
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
    break;
```

To reset the column value to *empty string*, add this in your resource model:

```
protected function _prepareDataForSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $data = parent::_prepareDataForSave($object);
    if ($object->getData('your_column_name') === '') {
        $data['your_column_name'] = '';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried and it's normal.

```
              $order->setData('customer_note', new Zend_Db_Expr(''));
              try {
                       $order->save();
                } catch (Exception $e){
                      echo $e->getMessage();  exit;
                }
```